# How would I make this code responsive/better using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the HTML code. I am good with coding in react.js and vue.js, but I am having a hard time getting the sense of making things responsive. I dont have experience with it. But got to start somewhere. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Right now, if you make the screen size smaller. It looks horrible.

Html/bootstrap

```
<section id="info" class="py-3 ">
    <div class="container text-white">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="text-white title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
        <p class="text-white cyp-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
          <div class="placeholder mx-auto"></div>
          <h1 class="text-center exp"> Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 justify-content-center">
          <div class="placeholder mx-auto"></div>

          <h1 class="text-center exp">Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
#info{
  height: 515px;
  width: 732px;
  background: #151515 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;

}

.cyp-para{
  padding: 0px 200px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.placeholder{
  width: 236px;
  height: 283px;
  background: grey;
}

.title{
  font-size: 38px;
}

.exp{
  font-size: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap, you can use break-point classes to make your code responsive.

Make small changes like below and your code will look better:

```
<section id="info" class="py-3 ">
    <div class="container text-white">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="text-white title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
        <p class="text-white cyp-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-center">
          <div class="placeholder mx-auto"></div>
          <h1 class="text-center exp"> Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 justify-content-center">
          <div class="placeholder mx-auto"></div>

          <h1 class="text-center exp">Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I have included **col-12** and **col-md-6** classed in your code. Which means till medium size devices, you have 12 column divs i-e 1 full column width div, and when your screen size becomes medium and above medium you'll have two column's per row